# ListView sometimes does not react on tap on an element

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, blocked

I have a ListView in an activity. The list elements are generated from a BaseAdapter. The list is continously growing as the user scrolls down on the screen. Actually an AsyncTask is responsibe to download data from the internet and generate the View elements for the ListView.

Each View element has a set onClickListener. The OnClickListener class starts a new activity...

The problem is that sometimes the GUI does not react on the click action.
e.g.
1. start the app
2. tap on the first element -> nothing happens
3. tap on the 2nd element -> nothing happens
4. scroll down a but -> both corresponding activities appear (on each other)

**ListAdapter:**

```
private class HirdetesListaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private GSResult hirdetesek;
    private final Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private SparseArray<ImageDownloaderThread> imageDownloadThreads;
    private ListViewWorker worker;
    private int thresHold = 45;
    private ArrayList<View> views;
    private boolean isWorkerThreadRunning = false;

    public HirdetesListaAdapter(final Context context, GSResult result) throws IOException {

        this.context = context;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        initAdapter(result);

    }

    public void initAdapter(GSResult result) {
        if (views == null) {
            views = new ArrayList<View>();
        } else {
            views.clear();
        }
        hirdetesek = result;
        imageDownloadThreads = new SparseArray<ImageDownloaderThread>();
        worker = new ListViewWorker();
        worker.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Log.v("bar2", "HirdetesListaAdapter.getCount()=" + views.size());
        return views.size();
    }

    @Override
    public GSHirdetes getItem(int arg0) {
        Log.v("bar", "HirdetesListaAdapter.getItem(" + arg0 + ")");
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Találatok: " + gsr.size(),
        // 100000).show();
        return hirdetesek.get(arg0);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        synchronized (worker) {
            worker.notify();
            Log.v("thread", "Working thread notified");

            worker.cancel(true);
            Log.v("thread", "Working thread cancelled");

            for (int i = 0; i < this.imageDownloadThreads.size(); i++) {
                imageDownloadThreads.get(i).cancel(false);
                Log.v("thread", "ImageDownloadThread " + i + " cancelled");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        Log.v("bar", "HirdetesListaAdapter.getItemId(" + arg0 + ")");
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if ((lv.getLastVisiblePosition() + thresHold) > views.size()) {
            synchronized (worker) {
                if (!this.isWorkerThreadRunning) {
                    Log.v("wthread", "Resuming worker thread");
                    worker.notify();
                    isWorkerThreadRunning = true;
                }
            }
        }

        synchronized (imageDownloadThreads) {
            if (imageDownloadThreads.get(position) == null) {
                Log.v("ithread", "Storing download thread: " + position);
                ImageDownloaderThread thread = new ImageDownloaderThread();
                imageDownloadThreads.put(position, thread);
                thread.execute(position);
            }
        }

        Log.v("thread", "getview finished for " + position);

        return views.get(position);
    }

    private class ListViewWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Log.v("thread", "ListViewWorker started");
            int buffer = 20;
            int i = 0;
            try {
                while ((views.size() != gsr.size()) && !this.isCancelled()) {
                    Log.v("thread", views.size() + "/" + gsr.size());
                    if (buffer != 0) {
                        views.add(i, makeView(i));

                        ResultActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                lv.addFooterView(views.get(views.size() - 1));
                            }
                        });
                        i++;
                        buffer--;
                    } else {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            try {
                                Log.v("wthread", "Pausing worker thread");
                                buffer = 20;
                                this.wait();
                                HirdetesListaAdapter.this.isWorkerThreadRunning = false;
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private View makeView(int position) {
            Log.v("thread", "ListViewWorker.makeView(" + position + ")");
            GSHirdetes hirdetes = hirdetesek.get(position);

            View hirdetesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hirdetes_listaelem, null);
            TextView hirdetesName = (TextView) hirdetesView.findViewById(R.id.hirdetesListaElemView_TextView_Name);
            TextView hirdetesAr = (TextView) hirdetesView.findViewById(R.id.hirdetesListaElemView_TextView_Ar);
            TextView hirdetesKategoria = (TextView) hirdetesView.findViewById(R.id.hirdetesListaElemView_TextView_Kategoria);
            hirdetesName.setText(position + ". " + hirdetes.getHirdetesName());
            // hirdetesName.setText(Integer.toString(position));
            hirdetesAr.setText(hirdetes.getHirdetesPrice());
            hirdetesKategoria.setText(hirdetes.getCategory());

            ImageView hirdetesImage = (ImageView) hirdetesView.findViewById(R.id.hirdetesListaElemView_ImageView_HirdetesCover);
            //hirdetesImage.setOnClickListener(new HirdetesImageListener(context, hirdetes));
            //hirdetesView.setOnClickListener(new HirdetesListaListener(context, hirdetes));

            //views.add(position, hirdetesView);
            Log.v("gui", "ListViewWorker.makeView(" + position + ") finished");
            return hirdetesView;
        }
    }

    private class ImageDownloaderThread extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Bitmap> {

        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private TextView percent;
        private URL imageUrl;
        private View view;
        private int sorszám = -1;

        public void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // while (threadCounter >= threadPool) {
            // try {
            // Log.v("konti","threadCounter:"+threadCounter+" threadPool:"+threadPool);
            // Thread.sleep(10);
            // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            // e.printStackTrace();
            // }
            //
            // }
            //
            // threadCounter++;

        }

        public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
            float percentValue = (float) progressBar.getProgress() / progressBar.getMax();
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
            String percentString = df.format(percentValue * 100) + "%";
            percent.setText(percentString);
            // Log.v("konti", percentString);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            sorszám = params[0];
            imageUrl = hirdetesek.get(sorszám).gethirdetesCoverImageUrl();

            view = views.get(sorszám);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.hirdetesListaElemView_ProgressBar_ImageDLProgressBar);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            percent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hirdetesListaElemView_TextView_ImageDLPercent);
            if (imageUrl == null) {
                return null;
            }

            Log.v("thread", "Starting ImageDownloaderThread for " + sorszám);

            int size;
            try {
                size = imageUrl.openConnection().getContentLength();
                progressBar.setMax(size);
                InputStream is = imageUrl.openStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int read = 0;
                Log.v("gui", "Downloading image for " + sorszám + ": " + imageUrl.getPath());
                while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                    baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    // Log.v("net", "Image download progress: " +
                    // baos.size());
                    publishProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + read);
                }
                baos.flush();

                byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("exception", "thread");
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            ResultActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) (progressBar.getParent());
                    vg.removeView(progressBar);
                    vg.removeView(percent);
                }
            });
            ImageView im = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.hirdetesListaElemView_ImageView_HirdetesCover);
            if (bitmap == null) {
                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage_hu);
            } else {
                im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Listener**:

```
public class HirdetesListaListener implements View.OnClickListener {

GSHirdetes hirdetes;
Context context;

public HirdetesListaListener(Context context, GSHirdetes hirdetes){
    this.hirdetes = hirdetes;
    this.context = context;
    Log.v("konti","Listener: "+hirdetes.getHirdetesName());
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.v("konti","HirdetesListaListener.onClick(v) "+hirdetes.getHirdetesName());
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HirdetesActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("data", hirdetes);
    context.startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

Comment: post your adapter and click listener code

Comment: code attached to the description, thx

Comment: if you want seperate clicklisteners **inside** a list item, make those variables final. Like: `final ImageView hirdetesImage = ...`

Comment: thanks, but unfortunatelly this did not do the trick :( anyway why do you think it should?

Answer (score 0):

you should use this code:

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item at pos "+arg2+" clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   });
```

Comment: Why? :) In the View I have an image and some text and I would like to do different action if the user taps on the image or on the text.

Comment: although it definately solved the problem. in the other hand now I can't differentiate if the user tapped on the image or the text

Comment: ok sorry. I did not realize that you want to differentiate two click action in the element.